# Sequencing rules and side effects for the operators

Tags: c++, c++11

Is the following code have well defined behavior:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
...
void foo (fs::path const& dir, fs::path file)
{
  file = dir / std::move (file); // Is it ok?
}
```

if we assume that we have `operator/ (path const& a, path&& b)` that modifies its second rvalue argument?

PS. This is not a boost-specific question. Boost filesystem library was only used as a example of the context where such a question may arise. The question is about of the safety of using `x = y / move(x)` expressions in C++, when *x,y* is a classes and *operator/* takes rvalue reference and can modify it.

Comment: Consider adding flag `boost`

Comment: Boost filesystem's `operator/` takes two const lvalue references. Is this actually a question about `path` objects, or is it a general question about rvalues? And why does the title mention sequencing rules?

Comment: @interjay It's the general question about c++11 expression sequencing rules. I used boost just to show some surrounding context for my question. I know the current implementation takes const lvalue refs and my code is fine, but this may be changed somewhere in future if they add functions optimized for rvalue references. So my concern is: if my code remain valid is such a case or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to this one, where the overloaded operators are resolved:

```
file.operator=(operator/(dir, std::move(file));
```

This is safe. Evaluation of the function arguments is sequenced before the function call, and although the evaluation of the method subject is unsequenced with respect to arguments, there is nothing to do there, so the modification of `file` cannot interfere with simply using `file` as an lvalue.